# How to make parallel requests in redux saga in array map loop into firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, redux, redux-saga

So i have array of ID's of users. I want to get data about them from collection. This is the pice of saga:

```
 const fetchedMembers = yield all(tasksObject[task].members.map( member => {
//member has id of user!
              const user = call(() => db.collection('users').doc(member).get())
              const userData = user.data()
              return {
                uid: member,
                ...userData
              }
            }))
```

But i have mistake in my code. How to spell it correct?

Answer (score 0):

The array passed to `yield all` should be an array of effects. If you refactor slightly you can do something like:

```
// define this helper generator
function* fetchMember(member) {
  // note the addition of the `yield` here before `call`
  const user = yield call(() => db.collection('users').doc(member).get())
  const userData = user.data()
  return {
    uid: member,
    ...userData
  }
}

...

 const fetchedMembers = yield all(tasksObject[task].members.map(
   // the array being passed to `yield all` is now an array of `call` effects
   member => call(fetchMember, member)
 ));
```